# Word 2010 Show Table only in footer of last page

Tags: ms-word, footer

I've a template for word. In header and footer I've got logos of my company. The data of word is generating automatically from ERP program (that works great).

I only want to show some table with data on last page. I've tried this [this method](http://legalofficeguru.com/different-footer-on-last-page/) But it only works for text. When I'm updating the field the table and it's content disappear.

Anyone knows how to apply this method on table? It must to be automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same method works for block level content such as paragraphs or tables. Simply follow the same steps but instead of typing "Initials" insert your table there. Make sure to use speechmarks in the conditional e.g it should look like this `{ IF {PAGE} = {NUMPAGES} "" "(table)" }`